# Two geometries not at same place

Tags: postgis, intersection, spatialite, postgis-2.0, map-matching

In the picture1 shown there is a linestring which is Area2 and a buffer of linestring which is Area1. I want to include Area2(linestring in picture) in the buffer but I cannot increase the size of the buffer because then I will have other extra street from Area2 as well. I have used ST_Snap as well as ST_SnapToGrid but nothing is working.

Is there some other way in postgis that this weird problem is solved without increasing the size of the buffer?

If I increase the size of buffer I will have small line(Extra Area2 line) in picture2 which I dont want in geometry.

Do I need map matching in this case?

or there is some another technique to get this line inside buffer?

or is there any technique to move both Area1 and 2 to same coordinates?

In the end I want all Area2 lines in the buffer without having the extra lines (extra line means here which is shown in picture2).

Area1 and Area2 geometry shapes are same except there are some extra lines in Area2 which I dont want by comparing with Area1.

PICTURE1 showing the difference between geometries. The blue buffer is Area1 and line is Area2. I want Area2 in buffer

[image]

PICTURE2 If I increase the size of buffer the small line is also included which I dont want

[image]

Picture3 :Another Example If I increase Buffer size it will have more purple linestring from Area 2 which I dont want
[image]

Comment: The Area2 in picture2 is not seen in picture1. where is it in picture1?

Comment: Oh sorry I can edit the photo it is behind the buffer which is purple line

Comment: please mention what you have done till now.

Comment: Picture is edited. After getting the Area2 with extra lines I wanted to remove them.So I tried to move both these linestring  Area1 and Area 2 at same location using ST_snap and ST_snaptogrid but my technique failed beacause ST_snap only snaps the vertices together not the original segment. My final plan was to move them together at same place and getting there difference out. As Area1 and Area2 shapes are same except there are some extra lines in Area2 which I wanted to remove by getting the difference but i could not get them at same location so I could not get the difference

Comment: Area2 and Area1 shape is same except there are some extra lines in Area2 which I dont want in Area2 by comparing with Area1. I had no other option to increase the buffer size but I dont want to because it includes extra lines from Area2

Comment: Have you tried using ST_Within

Comment: Yes I have tried st_within it is not useful because both the geometries are not completely inside

Comment: @neogeomat Both geometries are not completely inside therefore, ST_within cannot be used otherwise it will miss geometry. As you can see in picture1

Comment: @neogeomat if you want to see I can upload geometries

Comment: i think you should increse buffer size and use ST_within

Comment: @neogeomat but in this way I will have extra streets from Area2 how to ignore them?

Comment: ST_within should only select those features which are completely within area1.

Comment: @neogeomat if I increase the size of the buffer and use ST_within the small intersecting streets  of area2 will also come in buffer which I do not want how to ignore them?

Comment: @neogeomat if I select only those features which are completely within area1 with small buffer I will miss the lines of Area2 which I want and If I increase the size of buffer to include all the roads of area2 then I will get streets which I dont want

Comment: Does the individual linestring you want to buffer have a unique id, or is it a multiLinestring? Could you not buffer that single line with a where clause and union with existing buffer?

Comment: No they dont have a unique id. In Area1 I dont have the ids of linestrings where as in Area2 i have it.I actually dont want to union it because in Area2 there are some extra lines which I will like to remove.

Comment: so area 2 (line) does have an id for that linestring. If so buffer that line on its own and union that buffer with Area 1 (buffer area).